Kubuntu FTP shortcuts on desktop are opening with Firefox
I've upgraded Kubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04 and now the FTP desktop shortcuts (with the URL like "ftp://...") are opening with Firefox, not Dolphin. I've set Dolphin as default application, but nothing has changed. Meanwhile, if I click on the shortcut with right mouse button and choose "Open with Dolphin", it is opening with Dolphin without problems. Also "sftp://" shortcuts are opening by double click, as it was in 20.04. How can I restore the previous behavior?
